# Magento Upgrade Error from v1.4.x tp v1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I'm getting the following error when try to upgrade my Magento v1.4.1.1 to v1.7.0.2. Getting the following error when perform an upgrade.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:229:"Error in file: "/home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-31' for key 'UNQ_BY_CUSTOMER'";i:1;s:986:"#0 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.4.0.0.7', '1.6.2.0.1')
#2 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.4.0.0.7', '1.6.2.0.1')
#3 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/username/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Can any one have the solution for that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the major database issues on upgrading past 1.5.2.0 is a data-type change in the log files. The conversion fails because of Integrity constraint violations.

1. Truncate all log_ tables
2. Truncate report_event, report_compared_product_index, and report_viewed_product_index

This removes the offending records and allows the tables to be updated properly